# Get all elements by partial match of class attribute

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to use Nokogiri to display results from a URL. (essentially scraping a URL).

I have some HTML which is similar to:

```html
<p class="mattFacer">Matty</p>
<p class="mattSmith">Matthew</p>
<p class="suzieSmith">Suzie</p>
```

So I need to then find all the elements which begin with the word "matt". What I need to do is save the value of the element and the element name so I can reference it next time.. so I need to capture

```rb
"Matty" and "<p class='mattFacer'>"
"Matthew" and "<p class='mattSmith'>"
```

I haven't worked out how to capture the element HTML, but here's what I have so far for the element (It doesnt work!)

```rb
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
tmp = ""
doc.xpath("[class*=matt").each do |item|
    tmp += item.text
end

@testy2 = tmp
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy one-liner XPath-expression solution. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
doc.xpath('//p[starts-with(@class, "matt")]').each do |el|
  p [el.attributes['class'].value, el.children[0].text]
end
["mattFacer", "Matty"]
["mattSmith", "Matthew"]
```

Comment: yep - that seems to do the trick!! thanks! Is there a method to search any part of the class name? So if it was <p class='MrMattFacer'> how would I search? Basically it can be anything, but I want to catch the matt part! thanks for you help here :)

Comment: XPath has many functions like `starts-with`, e.g. `contains` and `substring`. http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#corelib

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
/*/p[starts-with(@class, 'matt')] | /*/p[starts-with(@class, 'matt')]/text()
```

This selects any `p` elements that is a child of the top element of the XML document and the value of whose `class` attribute starts with `"matt"` and any text-node child of any such `p` element.

**When evaluated against this XML document (none was provided!):**

```
<html>
    <p class="mattFacer">Matty</p>
    <p class="mattSmith">Matthew</p>
    <p class="suzieSmith">Suzie</p>
</html>
```

**the following nodes are selected (each on a separate line) and can be accessed by position:**

```
<p class="mattFacer">Matty</p>
Matty
<p class="mattSmith">Matthew</p>
Matthew
```

**Here is a quick XSLT verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select=
  "/*/p[starts-with(@class, 'matt')]
  |
   /*/p[starts-with(@class, 'matt')]/text()
  ">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The result of this transformation, when applied on the same XML document (above) is the expected, correct sequence of selected nodes**:

```
<p class="mattFacer">Matty</p>
Matty
<p class="mattSmith">Matthew</p>
Matthew
```

Answer (score 2):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
tmp = ""
items = doc.css("p[class*=matt]").map(&:text).join
```

Comment: typo `css("p[class*=matt]")`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is great, but another approach would be to use [Nikkou](https://github.com/tombenner/nikkou), which lets you match via regular expressions (without needing to be familiar with XPATH functions):

```rb
doc.attr_matches('class', /^matt/).collect do |item|
  [item.attributes['class'].value, item.text]
end
```